# Argument of complex number $(\tan \theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm given $-2+2\sqrt{3}i$. The question asks me to find the argument.

My attempt,

$\tan \theta=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{2}$

So $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$. But the given answer is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Why?

Comment: You left out a minus sign.

Comment: I just realised that. Thanks!

Comment: @Mathxx, See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your answer, you forgot a minus-sign. You should have $\tan \theta = -\frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and this gives the desired answer.

It may help to accompany these kinds of problems with a picture to prevent algebraic mistakes like this. $-2 + 2 \sqrt{3} i$ is the point $(-2, 2 \sqrt{3})$ in the complex plane, so this is in the second quadrant so you know that $\theta$ must be between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The right attempt must $\tan \theta = \frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{-2}$ and this gives the right answer.

So in the complex plane, this is in the second quadrant so you know that $\theta$ must be $\pi$ - $\frac{\pi}{3}$ = $\frac{2\pi}{3}$